# Nonlinear root solving libraries which accept a Jacobian in band-storage

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-equations, sparse-matrix, rootfinding

I'm in search for a library for solving large systems of non-linear equations, similar to [MINPACK](https://www.netlib.org/minpack/), but unlike MINPACK, can accept a Jacobian in [band-storage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Band_matrix#Band_storage).

My Jacobian is sometimes not invertible, so a method like the Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm in MINPACK, which can deal with singular Jacobians is important. Also, it would be nice if the package was in Fortran, but C/C++ is ok too.

I'm solving a system of ~10,000 nonlinear equations, with a non-zero diagonal about ~200 wide, so using band-storage is necessary. Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few options are

- [KINSOL](https://computing.llnl.gov/projects/sundials/kinsol) (Fortran and C interfaces are available; page 18 in the KINSOL documentation says you can use the banded solvers from LAPACK)
- [scipy.optimize.root](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.root.html#scipy.optimize.root) (particularly the large scale [nonlinear solvers](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.nonlin.html#module-scipy.optimize.nonlin))
- [fsolve](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/nonlinear-equations-with-jacobian.html) in MATLAB allows you to specify the Jacobian as a sparse matrix.
- [MATLAB codes](https://archive.siam.org/books/kelley/fr16/matlabcode.php) from the book "Iterative Methods for Linear and Nonlinear Equations"
- [Newton-Krylov method](https://openpipeflow.org/index.php?title=Newton-Krylov_method) in Fortran or MATLAB

Alternatively you could try and use a nonlinear minimizer like the [Ceres](http://ceres-solver.org/) solver from Google. This library supports sparse Jacobian matrices, but their Levenberg-Marquardt implementation is primarily aimed at nonlinear least squares problems. An answer over at [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26401539/can-i-solve-a-system-of-non-linear-equations-with-google-ceres-solver) explains how you might still be able to use it, but it involves the risk of converging to a minimum instead of the root.

Apart from KINSOL, none of these codes appear to be particularly adapted to banded matrices. In general if you store your Jacobian as a sparse matrix (e.g. CSR format) a back-of-the-envelope calculation says you should be able to reduce your memory consumption from ~100 MB to ~2 MB (assuming you are using 64-bit reals). Compared to a general sparse array, the LAPACK banded storage does not require the integer pointer arrays, so you would have some additional savings (~1 MB). In both cases I think you could expect to see a significant performance increase.

Comment: Thanks! I'm pretty optimistic about KINSOL. I'll try that. I did try scipy.optimize.root and I didn't work out - I couldn't work out to tell scipy the jacobian was sparse.

Comment: Let us know if it works out. One potential problem I see is the banded routines from LAPACK apply a LU factorization. To deal with a singular Jacobian it might be that a QR factorization is necessary (like used in MINPACK). I have located some routines for a banded matrix QR factorization here: https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/f77_src/band_qr/band_qr.html, but in this scenario you might need to modify MINPACK yourself.

Comment: One more library of potential interest is NewtonLib (http://elib.zib.de/pub/elib/codelib/NewtonLib/index.html). The routine NLEQ1 offers a global Newton method for full or banded Jacobians. A sparse version is also available in the routine NLEQ1S.